# Why does the code below causes Segmentation Fault (SIGSEGV)?

Tags: c++, arrays, segmentation-fault

**PROBLEM STATEMENT**
You are given a strictly increasing sequence of integers A1,A2,…,AN. Your task is to compress this sequence.

The compressed form of this sequence is a sequence of ranges separated by commas (characters ','). A range is either an integer or a pair of integers separated by three dots (the string "..."). When each range a...b in the compressed form is decompressed into the subsequence (a,a+1,…,b), we should obtain the (comma-separated) sequence A again.

For each maximal contiguous subsequence (a,a+1,…,b) of A such that b≥a+2, the compressed form of A must contain the range a...b; if b≤a+1, such a sequence should not be compressed into a range. A contiguous subsequence is maximal if it cannot be extended by at least one element of A next to it. It can be proved that the compressed form of any sequence is unique (i.e. well-defined).

Input
The first line of the input contains a single integer T denoting the number of test cases. The description of T test cases follows.
The first line of each test case contains a single integer N.
The second line contains N space-separated integers A1,A2,…,AN.
Output
For each test case, print a single line containing one string ― the compressed form of the given sequence.

**Constraints**

```
1≤T≤100
1≤N≤100
1 ≤ Ai ≤ 1000 for each valid i
A1 < A2 < …... <AN
```

Subtasks

Subtask #1 (100 points): Original constraints

**Example Input**

```
3
12
1 2 3 5 6 8 9 10 11 12 15 17
4
4 5 7 8
1
4
```

**Example Output**

```
1...3,5,6,8...12,15,17
4,5,7,8
4
```

**MY Code:**

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;
bool b[1005];
int a[1005];
int main()
{
    int test, i, j, size, count;
    cin >> test;
    while (test--)
    {

        for (i = 0; i < 1005; i++)
            b[i] = false;

        cin >> size;

        for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            cin >> a[i];
            b[a[i]] = true;
        }

        for (i = 0; i < 1005; i++)
        {
            if (b[i] == true)
            {
                cout << i;
                j = i;
                count = 0;
                while (b[j] == true)
                {
                    count++;
                    j++;
                }

                if (count > 2)
                {
                    i = j;
                    if ((j - 1) != a[size - 1])
                        cout << "..." << i - 1 << ",";
                    else
                        cout << "..." << i - 1;
                }
                if (count == 2)
                {
                    i = j;
                    if ((j - 1) != a[size - 1])
                        cout << "," << i - 1 << ",";
                    else
                        cout << "," << i - 1;
                }
                if (count == 1 && ((j - 1) != a[size - 1]))
                    cout << ",";
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
}
```

**MY Question:**
Above code runs perfectly on my device giving desired output. But when I am submitting this solution to
Online Judge , it says segmentation fault. It's sure that fundamentally I am accessing the memory incorrectly. Could you please show me where it is?

Comment: Either its usage of less memory than constraints or its illegal accessing of memory

Comment: Does it compile without warnings? That said, online competition programming is always a problem, because you have a third party in the loop and you can't even reproduce the issue locally. Questions like these tend to be of bad quality. BTW, as a new user, please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Atleast in CodeBlocks ,It is compiling without warning. And regarding quality, it has to be higher in general. Mostly because setters+testers in codechef come from lots of backgrounds and have varying experience.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with the quality statement. I wanted to say that questions where the correct solution means passing an online test tend to be of bad quality. The simple reason is that the environment where the tests are executed and often the tests themselves are not transparent. Basically, they often violate the requirement of a [mcve], offloading parts thereof to an online service.

Comment: Update: I would like to point out that when I declared variables globally the error message was not coming , but now judge said that the solution is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

b is defined a bool[1005]

In this part

```
for(i=0 ; i<4000 ; i++)
    b[i] = false;
```

You are writing false value 4000 times, exceeding the array size.
Overwriting past the array is allowed on the compiler but will have undefined behaviour in runtime.
In short: it can or can not cause a segfault.

Comment: My bad! I wrote it 4000. In actual code it is 1005 .I have edited accordingly and still its giving segmentation fault

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach given that the input data is in a file `input.txt`:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class Reader {
public:
    Reader(const std::string& filename) :
        filename_(std::move(filename)), is_(filename_)
    {
        is_.exceptions( std::ifstream::failbit | std::ifstream::badbit );
    }

    int get_N() {
        int N;
        is_ >> N;
        return N;
    }

    std::vector<int> get_ints(int N) {
        std::vector<int> v;

        v.reserve(N);
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++ ) {
            int value;
            is_ >> value;
            v.push_back(value);
        }
        return v;
    }

    int get_num_cases() {
        int num_cases;
        is_ >> num_cases;
        return num_cases;
    }

private:
    std::string filename_;
    std::ifstream is_;
};

bool start_range_cur( std::vector<int> &v, int j, int N )
{
    if ( j>= (N - 2) ) return false;
    return ((v[j+1] - v[j]) == 1) && ((v[j+2] - v[j+1]) == 1);
}

bool in_range_cur( std::vector<int> &v, int j )
{
    return (v[j+1] - v[j]) == 1;
}

void print_range( int min, int max, bool print_comma)
{
    std::cout << min << ".." << max;
    if (print_comma) std::cout << ",";
}

void print_single(int val, bool print_comma)
{
    std::cout << val;
    if (print_comma) {
        std::cout << ",";
    }
}

int main() {
    Reader is {"input.txt"};

    int num_cases = is.get_num_cases();
    for (int i = 0; i < num_cases; i++) {
        int N = is.get_N();
        std::vector<int> v = is.get_ints(N);
        bool in_range = false;
        int range_start;
        for( int j = 0; j< N; j++ ) {
            if (in_range) {
                if (j == (N - 1)) {
                    print_range(range_start, v[j], false);
                }
                else if (in_range_cur(v, j)) {
                    continue;
                }
                else {
                    print_range(range_start, v[j], true);
                    in_range = false;
                }
            }
            else {
                if (j == (N - 1)) {
                    print_single(v[j], false);
                }
                else if (start_range_cur(v, j, N)) {
                    in_range = true;
                    range_start = v[j];
                }
                else {
                    print_single(v[j], true);
                }
            }
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```